# JPA version confusion

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

I was asked by my client to use JPA 2.5, I have been searching in internet for JPA 2.5, according to lot of blogs and web sites there is no JPA 2.5, but JPA 2.1 is available. Now my question is 'Are JPA 2.1 and JPA 2.5 versions same?'.
It's a small issue but giving headache to lot of developers like me. Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe he meant [EclipseLink 2.5](https://eclipse.org/eclipselink/releases/2.5.php) which implements JPA spec 2.1? JPA specification is currently at version 2.1, with 2.2 on the way.

Comment: I think you are right Predrag Maric, Client has asked me to use Eclipse link implementation of JPA only. But client has specified to use JPA 2.5, Lets wait and see some other replies. But thanks for your valuable reply.

Comment: Lets wait and see some other replies: you won't get any. If your client want his app delivered within, say, the next 8 years you won't be using JPA 2.5.